# How to print an AngularJS variable out as a link in a Symfony2 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

I'm trying to print out a link in symfony2 while fetching the values with AngularJS. I am having problems with the curly brackets.

for example:

```html
<div id="columns">

  <div class="block" ng-repeat = "tip in tips">

    <img src="{{' {{ tip.imageDocument.webPath }}'}}" alt="">

    <div class="detail">
      <h2>{{ '{{ tip.title }}' }}  {{ '{{ tip.id }}' }}</h2>

      <p>{{ '{{ tip.introduction }}'}}</p>
      <a href="./tips/{{'{{ tip.id }}'}}" class="button">{% trans %}Read more{% endtrans %}</a>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

I figured that it works if I put curly brackets with around the angular variable '{{ variable '}}'

like this

`{{ '{{ variable }}' }}`

But this doesnt seem right to me.
Also the link doesnt work.
It gets printed out as %7B%7B%20tip.id%20%7D%7D which is obvious because of the curly brackets..

Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: There is some kind of encoding happening..which usually happens when u send data in a network

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `{{ '{{ variable }}' | raw }}`? It looks like escaping is turned on in your Twig configuration. It is by default.

**EDIT**: Ok, it looks like what is actually going on is that the browser is automatically "urlencoding" the curly brackets. I think the issue is not with Twig, in fact it is with Angular.js. You shouldn't use href when using Angular, you should use `ng-href` instead.

Comment: Just tried and it's not working. Great thinking though!

Comment: I have just edited the answer with an alternative. Also, if you could have a look at the HTML page source code and paste it that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to escape your inner curly brackets ?

```html
<div id="columns">

  <div class="block" ng-repeat = "tip in tips">

    <img src="{{' \{\{ tip.imageDocument.webPath \}\}'}}" alt="">

    <div class="detail">
      <h2>{{ '\{\{ tip.title \}\}' }}  {{ '\{\{ tip.id \}\}' }}</h2>

      <p>{{ '\{\{ tip.introduction \}\}'}}</p>
      <a href="./tips/{{'\{\{ tip.id \}\}'}}" class="button">{% trans %}Read more{% endtrans %}</a>
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

That's ugly but maybe this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `verbatim` tag anyway you want to display angular's variable.

For exemple:

```
{% verbatim %} {{ tip.title }}{% endverbatim %}
```

Now `{{ tip.title }}` will not parsed by twig but by angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **{% verbatim %}** to escape curlies from TWIG, and use **ng-*** attributes for src and href to allow AngularJS to parse it well, like this:

```
<div id="columns">
  <div class="block" ng-repeat="tip in tips">
    <img ng-src="{% verbatim %}{{ tip.imageDocument.webPath }}{% endverbatim %}" alt="">

    <div class="detail">
      <h2>{% verbatim %}{{ tip.title + ' ' + tip.id }}{% endverbatim %}</h2>

      <p>{% verbatim %}{{ tip.introduction }}{% endverbatim %}</p>

      <a ng-href="./tips/{% verbatim %}{{ tip.id }}{% endverbatim %}" class="button">
        {% trans %}Read more{% endtrans %}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More examples about **ng-*** attributes

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref